# Weber Quick start project fails to build

Tags: elixir, weber

I followed the [Weber Quick start](http://0xax.github.io/weber/), but the command `mix deps.get && mix compile --all --force && ./start.sh` resulted in the following output:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application myweber: {:bad_return, {{Myweber, :start, [:normal, 
[]]}, {:EXIT, {:undef, [{Cowboy, :start, 2, []}, {Weber, :start, 2, [file: 
'/Users/jonas/code/myweber/deps/weber/lib/weber.ex', line: 49]}, {:application_master, 
:start_it_old, 4, [file: 'application_master.erl', line: 269]}]}}}}
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Which ElixirLang, Weber and Platform do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was not your problem, it was Weber bug. I have fixed it and you can try last weber from master, it must work now.

Let me know if you will have problems.

Comment: I got new compilation problems: `== Compilation error on file lib/weber/session/session_manager.ex ==
could not compile dependency weber, mix compile failed. You can recompile this dependency with 'mix deps.compile weber' or update it with 'mix deps.update weber'
** (CompileError) deps/weber/lib/weber/session/session_manager.ex:35: function send/2 undefined
    lists.erl:1323: :lists.foreach/2
    erl_eval.erl:569: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    src/elixir.erl:140: :elixir.eval_forms/4
    src/elixir_lexical.erl:17: :elixir_lexical.run/2`

Comment: Yes, update please your Elixir to the Elixir-0.12.2 (last version), it will help